# VueJS Problem with DigitalPersona 4500 SDK import

Tags: vue.js, sdk, ecmascript-5, hid, digital-persona-sdk

I bought one digital persona 4500 and I want to know if it works with VueJs project ? If yes, can you let me know a tutorial where I can try to do it ?

I have an error on importing the Fingerprint module with VueJs. I am following this tutorial : https://hidglobal.github.io/digitalpersona-devices/tutorial.html . But i have an error with the import of websdk in one es5 bundles (VueJS). Why is that happening ?  This is the error : https://github.com/hidglobal/digitalpersona-devices/issues/4. But it doesnt solve the problem for now.

Here is the error :
[image]

Fyi :

I already added this to my index.html file :

[image]

I have tried all they say in the issue but nothing work.

Comment: Hello bro, I want to implement DP to my Vue JS project, you managed to solve the integration. Could you support me?

Comment: Hello, sorry still didn't solve it. The support HID just sent me an URL to they just sent me this URL : https://commerce.hidglobal.com/collections/development-center/products/access-to-the-digitalpersona-touchchip-developer-center to buy ther portal access. Sorry :(